# Bootstrap table and pagination pagination plugin 3 pagination in single page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap plugin for paginating the table rows/items.

http://bootply.com/93573

I am using this pagination concept 3 table(3 pagination box) in single page,its working only one time for 1st table 2nd and 3rd,its not working properly, can you please give me a solution for this scenario.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#singlepage').pageMe({
       pagerSelector:'#Para1',
       childSelector:'.panel',
       perPage: 4,
       showPrevNext: false,
       numbersPerPage: 5,
       hidePageNumbers: false,
       showFirstLast: true
  });
  $('#singlepage2').pageMesupp({
       pagerSelector:'#Para2',
       childSelector:'.panel',
       perPage: 4,
       showPrevNext: false,
       numbersPerPage: 5,
       hidePageNumbers: false,
       showFirstLast: true
  });
  $('#singlepage3').pageMecarr({
       pagerSelector:'#Para3',
       childSelector:'.panel',
       perPage: 4,
       showPrevNext: false,
       numbersPerPage: 5,
       hidePageNumbers: false,
       showFirstLast: true
  });
});
```

ALL the pagination in single page
1st pagination looking like this
< 1 2 3 4 5 > [total records 20]
2nd pagination looking like this
< > [total records 35]
3rd pagination looking like this
< > [total records 8]
if i click the last link in 2nd and 3rd pagination its showing from 6 to last record
2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the **[`How to Ask`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#singlepage').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#Para1',childSelector:'.panel',perPage: 4,showPrevNext: false,numbersPerPage: 5,hidePageNumbers: false,showFirstLast: true});
  $('#singlepage2').pageMesupp({pagerSelector:'#Para2',childSelector:'.panel',perPage: 4,showPrevNext: false,numbersPerPage: 5,hidePageNumbers: false,showFirstLast: true});
 All the below in single page
1 pagination looking like this
< 1 2 3 4 5 >  [ total records 20]
2nd pagination looking like this
< >     [ here having 35 records]
3rd pagination looking like this
< >     [ here total records 8 ]